# extracting attributes from html using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a string that I got from outerHTML. It logs like:

```
var responseHtml = jQuery(data).find("#response")[0].outerHTML;
console.log(responseHtml);

Log:

<div id="response" hello="world" big="span" hey="there">&lt;\/div&gt;"
<div class="clear"></div></div>
```

I am trying to get it in a format so I can access 'world' like:`values["hello"] => "world"`

I am stuck here. What is the appropriate way to achieve it?

Comment: Firstly, all of those attributes are invalid, you should be using data-attributes. Secondly, you should access them simply as `$('#response').data('big')` etc.

Comment: You can get it with: `$('#response').attr('hello')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than creating invalid attributes, you should be using the `data` attribute like:

```
<div id="response" data-hello="world" data-big="span" data-hey="there"></div>
```

And then to get those values with jquery, you can do:

```
var response = $('#response');
response.data('hello');  // returns "world"
response.data('big');  // returns "span"
response.data('hey'); // returns "there"
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vfwx3jLd/)